# ClipboardViewer

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

[image][ClipboardViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html)

ClipboardViewer is a sample project in the Mac Developer Library, when I run the App(Xcode 5.0.2), I got some output(not belong to system but the app) in the console, but I search the whole project for "NSLog" and found nothing.

So where is these output came from?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: It would rather help to see some of the output. It may be logged by system libraries.

Comment: I added a picture. You can see the output is just some text in my clipboard. No "NSLOG" in the whole project.

Comment: Running it from Xcode 4 it doesn't produce any output at all.

Comment: Well, my Xcode is 5.0.2. Maybe the output caused by this?

Comment: I doubt, but I'll see if I manage to check today.